# How to search a product automatically in amazon in Selenium IDE Amazon website smoke test?

Tags: search, selenium-ide, smoke-testing

Using Google Chrome Selenium IDE Extension How to search a product automatically in amazon in Selenium IDE Amazon website smoke test ?

To solve that issue i tried to search in google search engine Using Google Chrome Selenium IDE Extension How to search a product automatically in amazon in Selenium IDE Amazon website smoke test ? and i found how ti make a complete automaticed somke test of a website using Selenium, but not my question and that didn´t work because i need only to solve my issue not doing it with other things